# ssh-add complains: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Tags: command-line, ssh, ssh-agent

I've been trying to get `ssh-add` working on a RaspberryPi running Raspbian.

I can start `ssh-agent`, when I do it gives the following output into the terminal:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-06TcpPflMg58/agent.2806; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=2807; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 2807;
```

If I run `ps aux | grep ssh` I can see it is running.

Then I try to run `ssh-add` in order to add my key passphrase, and I get the following:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `eval $(ssh-agent)`

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Your shell is meant to evaluate that shell code output by `ssh-agent`. Run this instead:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

Or if you've started ssh-agent already, copy paste it to your shell prompt (assuming you're running a Bourne-like shell).

`ssh` commands need to know how to talk to the `ssh-agent`, they know that from the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't quite understand how it works.  Thats very muchly appreciated.

Comment: Or you can enter ssh-agent bash and after the ssh-add will work

Comment: @Stephane, do I get it correctly that ssh-agent command just prints the output of it's execution while eval version actually runs the command?

Comment: @DenysS. Well no, it does its setup and then tells your shell how to update its environment to be able to contact it. It cannot do that by itself. It can start a new shell with the updated environment (that's what `ssh-agent bash` does), but it cannot update the memory of a separate process running a foreign command (your already running shell).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, if my ssh-agent is started on boot but I still have to eval it in my shell does it mean that it is not automatically evaluated for every shell and has to be configured somehow by the root user?

Comment: @KamijouTouma, I've reverted the edit. Please add that information in your own answer as I don't agree with all you've said in that edit.

Comment: @DenysS. you can add `eval $(ssh-agent)` to your `~/.bashrc` at any time, for any number of users.

Answer (score 47):

Try this one:

```
$ ssh-agent /bin/sh
$ ssh-add $yourkey
```

Comment: This actually worked for me where none of the other answers worked.

Comment: If you are using the fishshell, this answer works. `ssh-agent /usr/bin/fish`.

Comment: I get an error: "**Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.**"

Comment: @slackmart If you installed fish in BSD, its location is `/usr/local/bin/fish` (alternatively `/usr/ports/shells/fish`).  Thank the `whereis` command for helping me figure that out.

Comment: Great @cjm, I use Slackware Linux, and that's the path that works for me.

Comment: This worked on an ancient Fedora release 10 (Cambridge) box. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me as well. I was on ZSH previously...

Comment: This worked for me also, 
but can anybody explain what the "ssh-agent /bin/sh" does?

Answer (score 19):

This question has been also very well covered on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17848593/1810012).

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`

ssh-add
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes around `\`...\``. Without them, the split+glob operator is invoked on the output.

Answer (score 7):

If using csh as a shell ([FreeBSD PI](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi)) this could work:

```
eval `ssh-agent -c`
```

next you only need to do something like:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I get an error: "**Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.**"

Answer (score 5):

You may also use the following syntax:

```
ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add && echo Do some stuff here.'
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, if you go `ssh-agent sh -c "ssh-add -l"` it will tell you you have no identities.

Comment: Because you've to add it first, for example: `ssh-agent sh -c "ssh-add && ssh-add -l"` will print your identity.

Comment: `RUN ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa'`  worked for me in a dockerfile

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
go to `C:\$Installation_Folder$\Git\cmd`
and execute:

```
start-ssh-agent
```

It will open a cmd command and run the `ssh-agent` the right way.

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`  should then work.

Comment: "**bash: start-ssh-agent: command not found**"

Answer (score 2):

This was confusing, and has 2 possible good answers, depending on whether the user is attempting to add a ssh key on a Linux or on Windows (as I am). This probably doesn't answer the OP, but is an expansion for git-bash.  I run both Windows and Ubuntu for development, and my git installation is slightly different in each.

> Try this: go to C:\$Installation_Folder$\Git\cmd and execute:
>
> start-ssh-agent  It will open a cmd command and run the ssh-agent the
>   right way.

.. was a good Windows answer, but failed to specify that you were expected to go through Windows Explorer to find the Git installation folder, and run the the Windows shell would open on completion of step 1.
"go to C:\$Installation_Folder$\Git\cmd"

Step 2: you just need to double-click

```
start-ssh-agent
```

On step 3, you go back to git-bash or whichever *nix terminal emulator you are running and run ssh-add.  If you used the default name for the ssh public key, you don't have to add the name as ssh-add uses that automatically.

Answer (score 2):

There’s a couple of ways if you wish to use an identity with sudo,
e.g. `sudo npm install`.

**Long way**, but also gives you root access so you won’t need to use `sudo` a lot.

1. Run
   `sudo ssh-agent bash`
   This will ask for your password and after will run `ssh-agent` with the superuser’s privileges,
2. Navigate to your users’ .ssh folder
   `cd /home/user/.ssh`
3. From there you can run

   ```
   ssh-add id_rsa
   npm install git+ssh://git@YOUR-PROJECT-URL -g && npm link PROJECT-NAME
   ```

**Short way**, only your user (unless you want to sudo a lot)

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
ssh-add
sudo SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" npm install git+ssh://git@PROJECT-URL -g && sudo npm link PROJECT-NAME
```

Comment: `export` and `eval` work just as well as root provided root's login shell is Bourne like. If root's shell is csh or tcsh, use `eval \`ssh-agent -c\``

Comment: Note that you can also give `root` access to your ssh-agent by doing `sudo SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" npm install...`

Comment: Tried both also bash is bourne again shell and neither worked properly. all users on my debian jessie instance including root are set to use bash by default.

Comment: What did you try? `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` at the prompt of a bash shell running as root will work. You'll obviously need to run `ssh` from that shell or its descendant so they inherit the SSH_AUTH_SOCK env var. `eval "$(sudo ssh-agent)"; sudo ssh...` won't work because `sudo` by default doesn't pass the SSH_AUTH_SOCK env var.

Comment: i tried `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` ill be looking later to see if there is some sort of configuration error. Although the current way i have given this guide allows free control over which user you wish to be since your already root and can access any users id_rsa thats on the server. So once i get it working appropriately ill edit my answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas is this acceptable?

Comment: I still get an error: **key_load_private_type: Permission denied**

Comment: -1: using `sudo` is not relevant to the question and is dangerous advice for common usage.

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest solution does not have to be bad.**

You need neither `ssh-agent` nor `ssh-add` when you use a passwordless private key, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290333/11154841.

By this, I got rid of the error `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent. ssh-add exit code 2`.

That does not need to be insecure: you simply need to delete both keys of the key pair right after their usage. That means, you must delete the public key on the server and delete the private key on the client. It goes without saying: never use them again, do not even keep a backup somewhere.

*Mind that you can create the public key from a private key, but not the other way round.* Normally, it should suffice to simply delete the public key from the registered keys on your Git portal, but they should better be both deleted, so that the same public key can never ever be used again. Even if someone had stolen your private key, it would be of no use if you simply never use its public key again.

With a passwordless private key, you can even use it in Docker to get around any password entries. You can clone a git repo without any password, the passwordless private key is all you need. See [Dockerfile: clone repo with passwordless private key. Errors: “authentication agent” or “read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty”](https://superuser.com/questions/1633085/dockerfile-clone-repo-with-passwordless-private-key-errors-authentication-ag) as an example.