# How to automatically run "ssh-agent bash" and "ssh-add" when log in?

Tags: centos, login, ssh-agent

I have a scenario where, whenever a user logs into a CENTOS machine via SSH, I need to have the following commands run:

ssh-agent bash
ssh-add

[This other thread explains why I am using those commands:

[ssh-add complains: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48863/ssh-add-complains-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/48868)
]

I have tried putting those into .bashrc, but then when I log in via Putty, it seems like the log in hangs.

I have also tried putting the two commands in a shell script, and then running the shell script manually after logging in, but that is not working (it looks like only the "ssh-agent bash" is run).

So is it possible to get those 2 commands to be run when the user logs in?  And if so, how can I do that?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Is your keyfile protected by a passphrase?

Comment: `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` are run locally not on the remote machine.  What OS is running on the local machines? ... If it's Windows and you are using putty, maybe [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683092/how-to-run-ssh-add-on-windows#18683544) will be helpful....

Answer (score 3):

If you put

```
ssh-agent bash ssh-add
```

in your `.bashrc`, you'll get an infinite recursion: the shell executing `.bashrc` starts `ssh-agent`, which starts another copy of `bash`... which will again execute `.bashrc`, and the process will repeat.

You'll want something like this instead:

```
if [[ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" = "" ]]; then
    # on the first round, we do this...
    exec ssh-agent bash
else
    # ... and when ssh-agent is running, we do this instead.
    ssh-add
fi
```